# how to add dynamic port no in the gunicorn docker?

Tags: docker, gunicorn, docker-entrypoint

I am trying to give dynamic port, thread, and workers while running the docker image but i am getting an error

```
[root]# docker run -it  -p 8080:8080  --env-file ./env.list  ff50c09659a0
/usr/bin/gunicorn: line 4: import: command not found
/usr/bin/gunicorn: line 5: import: command not found
/usr/bin/gunicorn: line 7: from: command not found
/usr/bin/gunicorn: gunicorn: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/gunicorn: gunicorn: line 10: `    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])'
```

In the docker file I am using the ENTRYPOINT

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","gunicorn","-b :","$port","-w","$worker","-t","$thread","--graceful-timeout","$time","api:APP"]
```

Can anyone suggest why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys got it solved just by changing the ENTRYPOINT

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c","gunicorn -b :$port -w $worker -t $thread --timeout 300 --graceful-timeout $time api:APP"]
```